# Custom JQuery is not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have written JQuery for my website search functionality. Its working fine when I am using separate file. But when I included same JQuery file in wordpress its not working as required.
My question is how to include this code in wordpress

Code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function () { 
 var filter = $('#search').val();
  $('.et_pb_row').each(function() {

        $(this).find("h3:not(:contains('" + filter + "'))").parent().hide();
        $(this).find("h3:contains('" + filter + "')").parent().show();
     });
 });
```

Comment: **1.** Check console if you're getting error related to `$`, if yes, then use `jQuery` instead of `$` to reference jQuery. **2.** Wrap the code in jQuery **3.** You can use `$(this).val()` in handler to get the search text **4.** No need of `each` here, `$(".et_pb_row h3:not(:contains('" + filter + "'))").parent().hide();` and `$(".et_pb_row h3:contains('" + filter + "')").parent().show();`

Comment: I have  used jQuery inplace of $ then it showing error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Same think when I tried to wrap code insode "jQuery(document).ready(function()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you have WordPress loading onto your template.

In your head file, ensure you have this loaded in

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Next, WordPress has to use `noConflict` mode or use the base `jQuery` call instead of `$`.

Try this

```
jQuery('#search').keyup(function () { 
    var filter = jQuery('#search').val();
    jQuery('.et_pb_row').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find("h3:not(:contains('" + filter + "'))").parent().hide();
        jQuery(this).find("h3:contains('" + filter + "')").parent().show();
    });
});
```

You should also ensure that all your jQuery code is wrapped in the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //code to run here
});
```

Comment: I have  used same code that you have provided then it showing error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Same think when I tried to wrap code insode "jQuery(document).ready(function()".

Comment: that means you don't have jquery loaded into your site. Try the above amendments

Comment: Then your jQuery code will be incorrect which will be based on your HTML

Comment: But it was working in simple html page.. I checked script in simple html file then I included into Wordpress.

Comment: I have created JSFiddle for using home page of website without css. Link : https://jsfiddle.net/3q7a95hq/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3q7a95hq/3/ fixed, but it is case sensitive. Your HTML is way off of what you were trying to do within the javascript, try using console logs to see what is and isnt get selected using different `each()` functions and you will see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help and jsfiddle. I am still not able to make it run on wordpress site. JSFiddle is working fine but dont know why not working on wordpress. There is no error in console. I tried to use console.log to print hello as soon as function get called but it not even showing hello in console. My website URL is dev.techhorizon.in/githa   and js is inside the file search.js..... and link for jsfiddle with css : http://jsfiddle.net/3q7a95hq/4/                     thanks in advance. I am not that familiar with jquery and wordpress working. Please bear with me.

Comment: Hi... Can you please check and let me know what is wrong with my JQuery

Comment: My above code works exactly how you wanted it to. It is case sensitive. On your website i can also not find anywhere to carry out the search functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your code work perfectly but its not working on wordpress. In my website their is search bar at top of page along with menu. I will really appreciate if you can check one more time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3859504 If you had read my answer in full, you would see i made a note about surrounding the jQuery code in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { // CODE HERE });` which fixes your problem.

Comment: Its working now after surrounding the jQuery code in jQuery(document).ready() function. Thanks  a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to try some trial and error method in fact.It can be because of jquery conflicts.

These are the possibilities coming in mind

1. Try placing your  jQUERY code above and below of `wp_head();`
2. Check if you are using the latest version of jquery file( or check if you use the same jquery file of the working file )
3. Try placing your  jQUERY code above and below of jquery file